# Importing sweetalert2 module returns 404 in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sweetalert2

Been following the online documentation and trying to use the sweetalert2 plugin in my angular2 application.

Unfortunately after i include this

```
import { default as swal } from 'sweetalert2';
```

I get a 404 error saying sweetalert not found

[image]

Comment: file is in node_modules ??

Answer (score 0):

Your import should be `import swal from 'sweetalert2';` or `import * as swal from 'sweetalert2;`

Answer (score 0):

As per [SweetAlert2 documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io), in case of ES6 Modules or TypeScript you should import SweetAlert2 like this:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'
```

Comment: When i try using the swal trigger i get the same error again

swal({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: 'Do you want to continue',
                    type: 'error',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
                })

Comment: Did you add import 'sweetalert2'; in your app or shared module?

Comment: Yes i did, import works, but when i includel the swal() function, it throws up the erro

Comment: import swal from 'sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2.all.js'; 

But it's breaking angular2 build

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize the plugin by referencing the necessary files:

> ```
> <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-s/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
> ```

You can also include the stylesheet separately if desired:

```
> <script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet"
> href="sweetalert2.min.css">
```

Or

// ES6 Modules or TypeScript

> import swal from 'sweetalert2'

// CommonJS

> const swal = require('sweetalert2')

2. Call the sweetAlert2-function after the page has loaded

> ```
> swal({
>   title: 'Error!',
>   text: 'Do you want to continue',
>   type: 'error',
>   confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
> })
> ```